# How to Indent Child UL items

Tags: css, html-lists

Hello ive spent about 4 hours on this tonight and ive had to give up with all my hair torn out. I try not to ask simple enough css questions but i just cant get a grip with list items or more specifically child list items. One rule for all i find.

```
<li class="parent open">
<span class="parent open"></span>
<a href="/member-tags/forum">Member Tags</a>
<ul>
<li class="parent open">
<span class="parent open"></span>
<a href="/world-komp/forum">world of komp</a>
<ul>
<li>
<a href="/komps-bets/forum">komps bets</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/komps-daily-diary/forum">komps daily diary</a>
</li>
...
```

I was wanting to make the indent smaller on my child items and also the text a little smaller to accomodate them. Here's a screen shot. the black things on the left are supposed to be arrows indicating where i was hoping to have my child items.
[image]

you can view the code on my website
http://onlinebanter.com

all help appreciated as i really have spent too much time trying to figure this out and it is not the first night i have tried.

thanks

```
ul.jquerymenu li.parent {
  background-image:none;
  list-style:none none;
}
.block ul {
  margin:0;
  padding:0 0 0.25em 1em;
}

ul.menu {
  border:none;
  list-style:none;
  text-align:left;
}

ul {
  list-style-type:disc;
}
.block ul, .block ol {
  margin-left:2em;
  padding:0;
}

ul, ol, dd {
  margin-bottom:1.5em;
  margin-left:2em;
}

ul.menu li {
  margin:0 0 0 0.5em;
}

li, li.leaf, ul.menu li, .item-list ul li {
  line-height:150%;
}

ul.menu li, ul.links li {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

ul.jquerymenu li.parent {
  background-image:none;
  list-style:none none;
}

ul.menu li {
  margin:0 0 0 0.5em;
}

li, li.leaf, ul.menu li, .item-list ul li {
  line-height:150%;
}

ul.menu li, ul.links li {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant fragment of the HTML here? Links die, while this question will remain forever.

Comment: k sorry Frank. i hope this is right....block ul {
  margin:0;
  padding:0 0 0.25em 1em;
}
css_9832...b8010.css
ul.menu {
  border:none;
  list-style:none;
  text-align:left;
}
css_9832...b8010.css
ul {
  list-style-type:disc;
}
css_9832...b8010.css
.block ul, .block ol {
  margin-left:2em;
  padding:0;
}
css_9832...b8010.css
ul, ol, dd {
  margin-bottom:1.5em;
  margin-left:2em;
}

Comment: [code]ul.jquerymenu li.parent {
  background-image:none;
  list-style:none none;
}
css_9832...b8010.css
ul.menu li {
  margin:0 0 0 0.5em;
}
css_9832...b8010.css
li, li.leaf, ul.menu li, .item-list ul li {
  line-height:150%;
}
css_9832...b8010.css
ul.menu li, ul.links li {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

Comment: bah im not doing too well here. ill edit origianal post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your particular situation you can use the selector `.parent .parent ul`, like so:

```
.parent .parent ul {
margin-left: 1em;
font-size: 10pt;
}
```

.parent .parent ul finds a ul element that is a child of an element with a class parent that is again a child of another element with a class parent.  Like this:

```
<tag class="parent">
  <tag class="parent">
  </tag>
</tag>
```

In that example, there is an element (tag) with a class of parent, inside of an element (tag) with a class of parent.  So the CSS could be `.parent .parent { ... }`

Now, put a UL element in there:

```
<tag class="parent">
  <tag class="parent">
     <ul>
     </ul>
  </tag>
</tag>
```

Now the CSS selector could be `.parent .parent ul { ... }`

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks boz. i have to say that im completely confused as ever with this now. As i thought franks suggestion done as we all thought. Im presuming that i need to find some differant named selectors to the ones youve suggested? Ill try that code just as you say and im sorry about my confusion. I just cant get a grip with list items and if anyone needs proof there is a thread in my css tag on my website showing my confusement.

Comment: @RegGordon I'll add an explanation.  But basically, from right to left: select a ul element, that is a child of an element with parent class, that is again a child of a parent class.

Comment: ah hah brilliant it worked boz. i dont know how it worked but it worked lol

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>...
  <ul>
    <li>....
```

With the following CSS applied to it:

```
ul {
  margin-left: 2em;
}
```

Just change the value to `1em` and the indent will be less.

Comment: thanks frank ill give it a go but i think that will effect all list items and i just want to affect the children. ill give it a go though

Comment: In that case you can select just deeper levels with the selector that @bozdoz used in his answer.